# Puppet parse hiera in inline_template

Tags: puppet, hiera, yaml

I have got some .yaml hiera file with:

```
iptables::test:
  ip:
    1.1.1.1  : 'adm-1'
    2.2.2.2  : 'adm-2'
    3.3.3.3  : 'adm-3'
```

And i want to parse this file in inline_template. I write:

```
$variable1 = hiera('iptables::test.ip')
$variable2 = inline_template("<% @variable1.each do |key,value| %>Allow From <%=key %> #<%=value %>\n<% end -%>")
```

But get an error:

```
 Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item iptables::test.ip in any Hiera data file and no default supplied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with either your data structure or your logic, or both. I am not sure I have enough here to sort out which.

The first issue I see is your `hiera()` lookup function cannot lookup the nest `ip` hash directly. Your Hiera key is just `iptables::test`. You can get the full value of that via lookup and parse it further if needed.

```
$variable1 = hiera('iptables::test')
```

If you don't need the nested `ip` hash, your `inline_template()` works as written. Your data structure would just be a single hash.

```
---
iptables::test:
  1.1.1.1: adm-1
  2.2.2.2: adm-2
  3.3.3.3: adm-3
```

If you need the nested hash, then you need a nested loop.

```
$variable2 = inline_template("<% @variable1.keys.each do |ip| %><% @variable1[ip].each do |key, value| %>Allow From <%= key %> #<%= value %>\n<% end %><% end %>")
```

---

Putting it together to demonstrate:

```
$ cat test.pp 
$variable1 = {
  ip  => {
    '1.1.1.1' => 'adm-1',
    '2.2.2.2' => 'adm-2',
    '3.3.3.3' => 'adm-3',
  },
}

$variable2 = inline_template("<% @variable1.keys.each do |ip| %><% @variable1[ip].each do |key, value| %>Allow From <%= key %> #<%= value %>\n<% end %><% end %>")

notice($variable2)
```

```
$ puppet apply test.pp
...
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): Allow From 1.1.1.1 #adm-1
Allow From 2.2.2.2 #adm-2
Allow From 3.3.3.3 #adm-3

Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost in environment production in 0.02 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

My test here did not use Hiera, because Hiera is just a way to bring data from outside of a Puppet class. I wanted to demonstrate this way because it will be easier for you to isolate your problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Problem was in old version puppet.